# Updating Facebook status through Jsoup

Tags: java, facebook, html-parsing, jsoup

I want to update my Facebook status through my Java console application. I am using the Jsoup HTML parser.

First I need to login to the Facebook account.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.facebook.com")
  .data("email", "myemailid")
  .data("pass", "mypassword")
  // And other fields which are being passed in post request.
  .userAgent("Mozilla")
  .post();
```

When I print `doc` on the console, I can see that I am able to log in, but that login is through Facebook Mobile. Why not the PC version?

Is it possible to use this `doc` variable to update my Facebook status?

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this may work in the end, it is not a proper way to communicate with Facebook.

Facebook has [an official API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) which should be used to post updates. [restfb](http://restfb.com/) is a nice java client for that API.

Comment: Like browser , when we login once it stores a cookie so no need to login again , but when after writing the above code in eclipse if i again write same code without giving password and username  , it took me to the login page.. So does eclipse tool somewhere stores cookie?

Comment: Because you shouldn't use the above code. You shouls use the api

Comment: Facebook has many cookies, performs login over https, and other security implications.